# @JsonAnySetter annotated method sometime gets a value and sometimes get an empty String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, lombok, jackson-databind

I have a collection of PoJos that map the response from an API provided by another team at my company. They have a habit of adding new properties to the json that they send out, without notice. So, after some research I came across the @JsonAnySetter annotation and wrote a simple base class that is extended by all of my model objects:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BaseResponseObject implements Serializable {
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void ignored(String name, Object value) {
        LOGGER.warn("Unrecognized value in response from backend in {} - {} : {}", this.getClass().getName(), name, value);
    }
}
```

I have tried this both with value set as Object as above and with it typed as String. Either way, when I get back a value that I care about mapping but have not yet mapped, the value parameter is an empty String. But when the value is an complex object, as opposed to a String, and value is an Object then I see the full object printed in my log.

The issue is that based on the log messages I was getting before mapping a certain value, I thought that the value was coming back to my code as empty. But when I got it mapped, it is not empty! So, why does my @JsonAnySetter method sometimes log useful info and sometimes log an empty String?

EDIT ----
It occurs to me that the class level annotations could have an impact here so I've added them.

In response to @cyberbrain, yes the class I posted is a base class that all of my model objects extend. Here is an example of the type of model objects that extend the above parent class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ModelOne extends BaseResponseObject {
    String porpertyOne = "";
    String propertyTwo = "";
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add to your POJOs: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`
This means if there new field is added on JSON which represents your Model then Jackson will not throw UnrecognizedPropertyException while parsing JSON in Java.

Comment: I am not getting any parsing errors since adding the @JonAnySetter to my ignored method. In am just finding that when I actually care about the contents of the value variable, it is set to an empty string

Comment: Can you also add an example of a JSON where this happens? And it could get tough to debug with all that Lombok magic going on, as jackson-databind is looking for the getters and setters and annotations on them could be useful.
Also: what is "your" code? What you are showing looks much like a base class without any fields to be filled.

Comment: Unfortunately the json that is causing this issue contains PHI (Protected Health Information) so I cannot post the real the actual data but I will see if I can jin up a mock file.

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments. I looks like my original question is moot. After looking more closely at the responses I have been using, I should be getting an empty string. The other team is not yet sending the data I was expecting.... Oh well!